# What sort of variable is being set here?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter

When I run this,

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32' python src/networkTraining.py src/LiviaNET_Config.ini 0
```

my code runs successfully.

However, when I run them as two separate lines,

```
THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32' 
python src/networkTraining.py src/LiviaNET_Config.ini 0
```

The code gives me this error:

```
TypeError: ('TensorType(float32, scalar) cannot store accurately value 
0.001, it would be represented as 0.001. If you do not mind this precision 
loss, you can: 1) explicitly convert your data to a numpy array of dtype 
float32, or 2) set "allow_input_downcast=True" when calling "function".', 
0.001, 'Container name "None"')
```

Why is this happening?

What kind of variable assignment is taking place? I ask because I can't run it in one shot on my jupyter notebook.

Comment: That is an environment variable, how exactly are you running this?

Comment: I run that on the command line. Why does it not work if I run them as two separate lines of code?

Comment: Well, it's an environment variable.  Just do `export THEANO_FLAGS=<whatever>` and then `jupyter notebook` in the same terminal

Comment: See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153587/environment-variable-assignment-followed-by-command and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97302/is-it-shell-portable-to-run-a-command-on-the-same-line-after-variable-assignment

Comment: Awesome. That worked, thanks. Is there any way I can do this from inside the notebook itself? I tried `%env THEANO_FLAGS='floatX=float32'` and `import os` `os.environ["THEANO_FLAGS"] = "floatX=float32"` both didn't work..

Comment: Probably would have to do it before theano is imported, just a guess.